# Creating Directories in Ubuntu with python

Tags: python

I am trying to create directory in Ubuntu using python and save my zip files in it. My code is working fine in windows but behaving weirdly with ubuntu.

```
import os
import zipfile
import datetime
from os.path import expanduser


home = expanduser('~')
zip_folder = home + '\\Documents\\ziprep'  # enter folder path where files are
zip_path = home + '\\Documents\\zips'        #enter path for zip to be saved

global fantasy_zip

def dailyfiles(weekly_file,today):
    today = str(today)
    try:
        os.mkdir(zip_path + today)
    except OSError:
        print("Creation of the directory %s failed" % today)
    else:
        print("Successfully created the directory %s " % today)
    for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(zip_folder):
        for file in files:
            if file.startswith(today) and not file.endswith('.zip') and file not in weekly_file:
                print("Zipping  - Filename " + file)
                zip_in = zip_path + today + "\\"
                fantasy_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_in + file + '.zip', 'w')
                fantasy_zip.write(os.path.join(folder, file),
                                  os.path.relpath(os.path.join(folder, file), zip_folder),
                                  compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

        fantasy_zip.close()



def main():
    weekday = str(datetime.datetime.today().weekday())
    today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
    dailyfiles(weekly_file,today)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Logically it should create a folder with todays date at the path specified. But it is creating Folder in ubuntu with the whole path at the same directory where m script is.

For example it is creating folder with name like this: '/home/downloads/scripypath'

Whereas I need '20191106' at the path which is specified in script. The code is working fine in windows.

Link to current [project file](https://workupload.com/file/ju4pW4x6)

Comment: Please truncate the code to only the relevant section.

Comment: it's better to use `/` then `\\\` when specifying path.

Comment: Because directories paths in windows and Linux are not the same, you can't use `\\foo\\bar` to create directories in Linux, that sould be `'foo/bar/'`.

Comment: @rdas truncate the code.

Comment: @c0x6a  its working for me. Now I am getting a different issue. But its this one is resolved. Just one question. I Linux I get an error Variable referenced before assignment. But not in windows. Why such behavior difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in ubuntu directory structure is totally different and they use \ instead of /.
>   so prepare your link as ubuntu file structure.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `home + '/Documents/ziprep/'`and `home + '/Documents/zips/'` on lines 8 and 9, respectively.

EDIT: Sorry, forgot why this should solve the problem. In Linux or Unix, directories use "/" instead of "\" (used in Windows) as directory separators.

Comment: Could you provide some information as to how this solves @Duck_dragon's question?

Comment: @PeonProgrammer Edited it just now. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Hi @Jainil Patel! I do believe that I did not copy any answer from this thread. My answer is authentic. In regards to you accusing me of copying your answer, I would never copy an answer that is completely wrong! Your answer states that Linux directories use '\' instead of '/'. According to official Ubuntu documentation (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview), it is stated that Linux use '/', which was my answer. Instead of wrongly accusing me of copying answers, you might as well check your answer first before posting it. Please think before you click.